# I cannot get qqnorm to work inside a FOR loop

Tags: r, loops, plot, subset

I am trying to build qq-plots for the prices of ten stocks.

I wanted to build those plots using a FOR loop, but I am getting error messages - how can I fix the code?

I downloaded the stock prices of stocks from yahoo finance. I only extracted the daily adjusted prices, then combine them into a dataframe with ten columns. I did not include dates in the dataframe.

the codes is as follows:

```
par(mfcol=c(2,5),mar=c(2,2,2,2))
for(varname in names(stocks)) {
  qqnorm(stocks[varname])
}
```

I get the error "Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix."

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to use the form: `stocks[[varname]]`

Answer (score 2):

`qqnorm` takes vectors on input:

> qqnorm(y, ...)
>
> **y**  The second or only data sample.

You can obtain `y` from your data frame like this:

```
df[[stock_name]]
df$stock_name
```

or, if you are dealing with a matrix:

```
mat[, col_number]
mat[, stock_name]
```

Here is a simple example:

```
s <- matrix(rnorm(1000), 100, 10)
colnames(s) <- letters[1:10]


for (i in colnames(s)){
  qqnorm(s[,i])
}
```